# mysql one to many relation with conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables events and events_visibility

events table and the column

```
id - title - all
```

events_visibility and its column

```
id - event_id - visibile_to - visibile_to_id
```

here visibile_to used who can see this events. here visibile to maybe Group A, Group B, Group C, so one event can have multiple entry in event_visibility

```
SELECT Event.*, EventVisibility.* FROM events AS Event 
LEFT JOIN events_visibility AS EventVisibility
ON 
  (Event.id = EventVisibility.event_id) 
WHERE 
 'Event.all' = 1 
 OR 
  (
    'EventVisibility.visible_to_id' = 2 AND 
    'EventVisibility.visible_to' = 159
 )
```

I want to fetch the unique events based on the visibility and if all, something like this 
this query not gave me the proper result.

Can you please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its maybe you wrote column inside single quotes. Try this

```
   SELECT Event.*, EventVisibility.* FROM events AS Event 
    LEFT JOIN events_visibility AS EventVisibility
   ON 
   (Event.id = EventVisibility.event_id) 
   WHERE 
   Event.all = 1 
   OR 
   (
    EventVisibility.visible_to_id = 2 AND 
    EventVisibility.visible_to = 159
    )
```